# When to use Angular mat-card component

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-card

I'm new to Angular, and of course to Angular material. One of the mysteries components of material I've met was [mat-card](https://material.angular.io/components/card/overview), I've read its description over and over, I searched the net, but ّI didn't understand when to use mat-card component. So my question is when do front-end developers use mat-card component practically?

Comment: The docs from material design cover the uses of a card: https://material.io/components/cards/# . Does the object you are trying to represent have text information and some sort of action?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky shame on me. I'll delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mat-card can be used to display things in the list view and not limited to the list view only but let's say you have user details like 100 in number now each user details will be in mat-card tag so you can easily create great UI experience to end-users.